# Spark to analyse large mbox Mailbox file using map reduce in Python

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, mbox

I have large mbox file which I can parse using the mailbox api and dump to csv

```
import mailbox
import csv
mbox = mailbox.mbox("emailfile.mbox")
for message in mbox:
with open('mail.csv','w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
    for message in mbox:
        data = [ (message['Date'],message['From'], message['To'], message['subject']) ]
        writer.writerows(data)
        print data
```

How can I do this using pySpark and map reduce?
I am not able to figure how to load the file into rdd and use the mailbox api in a map reduce fashion.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it and I have uploaded my code here - https://github.com/bbalegere/Spark-EmailDump-Analyser

I used formail command to split the mbox file into individual eml files and then used sc.wholeTextFiles to read the directory containing all the eml files and run parallel operations on it.